# Lumia 625 showing "update demo content" instead of "reset" icon

Tags: lumia

I did hard reset on my  Lumia 625 Dual Sim, after resetting, I got a " update demo content" instead of "reset" icon. Now Iam unable to reset my phone. plzzz help

Comment: Can you please share some pics and more detailed steps on what you did?

Answer (score 4):

phone->settings->about-> click on update demo phone.

when the pop-up screen comes up note that it says to update press yes or no. Now turn the phone to the right so it rotates to landscape. then rotate back to portait. now rotate to the left so the screen goes landscape and then rotate back to portait. You will notice it now says RESTORE DEMO DEVICE. this will erase all content,click yes and wait for it to finish. Congrats retail demo mode is off your device!!
cheers..

Answer (score 3):

Did the Phone work normally before you did the hard reset?
Anyway, you'll have to remove the demo software from your phone. Try flashing the latest stable Windows Phone version on your device using the [Nokia Software Recovery Tool](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDYQFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fexpertcentre.nokia.com%2Fde%2Farticles%2Fkbarticles%2FSeiten%2FNokia-Software-Recovery-Tool.aspx&ei=PclPVMHOKc3ZPanCgIgD&usg=AFQjCNEUAQ1f6CIwT5b0j-V9ycK0iLFYtg&sig2=NJHjsgXms-t3-2spByfolQ&bvm=bv.77880786,d.ZWU). This should fix it.